# How to detect wordpress theme using php

Tags: php, ajax

i have look for Wordpress theme detector but i have no idea how it works and how to detect wordpress activated theme into theme folder. like https://theseotools.net/wp-theme-detector

please help me how can i did this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this code for the purpose of readability.  Normally, people would spend more than 10 lines of code fetching the name of an active wordpress template.  There might be some minor adaptions needed, but nevertheless, this works.  So, first we fetch the source code for the home page.  Then we use regex to find style.css, then we use regex to fetch the name (refer to wordpress style sheet conventions), and **yay** we now have the name of the active theme.  You can even get the download URI from here, as well.

```
<?php
$targetSite = ""; // put your wordpress url here
$src = file_get_contents($targetSite);
preg_match("/\<link rel='stylesheet'.*href='(.*?style\.css.*?)'.*\>/i",$src,$matches);
$styleHref = trim($matches[1]);
$styleSrc = file_get_contents($styleHref);
preg_match("/\Theme Name:(.*?)\n/i",$styleSrc,$name);
echo(trim($name[1]));
?>
```

Comment: question is how to find active theme ?

Comment: The code is finding the active theme that is being used at whatever url you have entered.  It fetches the name from the stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you , you save my day, i dont know how it work , but it's perfact for me

Comment: Familiarize yourself a bit with regex and you'll be golden.  Basically, it grabs the source code for a URL entered and then searches the text for the correct file URL and then repeats the source code fetch and text search to get the name.

Comment: @nfn neil , is possible get all plugin list into wordpress from domain name

Comment: @nfnneil  is possible get all plugin list into wordpress from domain name

Comment: Oh, sorry forgot about that comment 1 sec

Comment: No, you can't... but you can fetch all front end plugins by using a regex.  If you open the home page you will see some files referenced as /plugin/ you can fetch the name from that.  Unfortunately,  there isn't strict naming conventions for this.

Comment: Thanks for replay @nfnneil, hhehe i have already try to fetch /plugins/ using regex, but most plugin have no css and js in home page. just some plugin has own css. so just i get some plugin using your regex trick . so i have need some another idea.

Comment: This will not work if any site has two style.css (one is from wp-content/themes and another is from wp-content/plugins)